# DTO doesn't respond with an error if pass a value of different datatype in nest application

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, nestjs, dto

Even if I have passed string values in number, the DTO simply accepts and doesn't respond with an error. Can anyone help me the same. Thanks in advance!

Mentioned below is my dto,

```
export class ListArticlesDto {
    search: string = null;

    limit: number = DEFAULT_PAGINATION_LIMIT;

    pageNumber: number = DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER;
}
```

I was expecting an error when I passed limit = "jhsdja" but it simply accepted the input!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you aren't making use of Nest's [`ValidationPipe`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe). You need to install `class-transformer` and `class-validator` **and** decorate your DTO with the appropriate decorators to tell `class-validator` about the type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
I did use, I have installed both the packages and it's working fine for "empty string validations". The problem is with the datatype.

Comment: From what you've shown, you're not telling class-validator about what types those should be. If you want better answers, provide more information

Comment: Thanks for the responses @Jay. I have got the solution and the solution was to use @IsInt(), @IsString() decorators with every fields inside DTO class. Thank you once agin!